# SQL Query: Fetch ordered rows from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Following are some entries from a table:

```
id      r_id        a_id        p_id
```

1       9           9           0
2       9           105         108
3       9           102         9
4       9           106         105
5       9           108         102

Is it possible to get the following output using SQL query

```
1       9           9           0
3       9           102         9
5       9           108         102
2       9           105         108
4       9           106         105
```

The idea is to sort the rows in such a way that a row with p_id = x should come below the row with a_id = x.

I hope question makes sense.

Regards,
Mayank

EDIT:
I'm looking this for PostgreSql

- The root item has a p_id = 0
- There are no missing links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive query (PostgreSQL version 8.4 or later):

```
/* test data:
CREATE TABLE foo (id, r_id, a_id, p_id) AS
    SELECT  1,9,9,0
    UNION ALL SELECT 2,9,105,108
    UNION ALL SELECT 3,9,102,9
    UNION ALL SELECT 4,9,106,105
    UNION ALL SELECT 5,9,108,102        
;
*/

-- the query you need:
WITH RECURSIVE sub(s_id, s_r_id, s_a_id, s_p_id, row) AS (
    SELECT id, r_id, a_id, p_id, 1 AS row FROM foo WHERE p_id = 0
UNION ALL
    SELECT id, r_id, a_id, p_id, (row + 1)  FROM foo JOIN sub ON s_a_id = p_id
)
SELECT * FROM sub ORDER BY row;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, just need an advice regarding performance. How much better/worse would it be to fetch all the values and then sort it in memory?

Comment: Use EXPLAIN ANALYZE to see how the query is executed and how much memory is used. You might need some changes in the settings for work_mem, depending on your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Following is adapted from a working SQL Server 2005 solution.

I have made some assumptions

- The root item has a `p_id = 0`
- There are no missing links

**SQL Statement**

```
;WITH RECURSIVE q AS (
    SELECT  *
            , 1 AS Level
    FROM    ATable 
    WHERE   p_id = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t.*
            , Level = Level + 1
    FROM    q
            INNER JOIN ATable t ON t.p_id = q.a_id          
)
SELECT  *
FROM    q
ORDER BY
        Level
```

Comment: The OP edited the question, he is looking for an answer compatible with a postgreSQL database. I won't downvote since you answered before the edit, but please consider editing your answer.

Comment: @Johann - I have never looked at postgreSQL but looking at the accepted answer and mine, you hardly notice any differences (The Recursive seems to be the only one). OP should have been able to work that out by himself.

Comment: Both the answers are acceptable. By the time I realized how it could be done using postgresql I got another answer. Now, I could accept only one answer :).

Comment: I agree but the fact is you explicitly say it is for SQL Server, you might want to remove that restriction if you are confident it works also for PSQL.

Comment: @Johan, @Mayank - I believe this would be all it takes. OP already got an answer but he could verify if it works.