# SQL Query: Fetch ordered rows from a table - II

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

Following are some entries from a table:

```
id      r_id        a_id        p_id
```

1       9           9           0
2       9           105         108
3       9           102         9
4       9           106         105
5       9           108         102
6       10           10         0
7       10           15         18
8       10           12         10
9       10           16         15
10      10           18         12

I'm looking for an SQL query that will give an output like:

```
1       9           9           0
3       9           102         9
5       9           108         102
2       9           105         108
4       9           106         105
6       10           10          0
8       10           12         10
10      10           18         12
7       10           15         18
9       10           16         15
```

Well, I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040933/sql-query-fetch-ordered-rows-from-a-table) but the question was not complete and I also got few excellent answers. Editing that question might make the answers unacceptable, so I did not edit and added this as a new question here.

- The root item has a p_id = 0
- For one r_id there can only be one p_id = 0
- The table shown on which Query need to be run may not be sorted with respect to root.
- I'm looking things to work in PostgreSql

EDIT:
The idea is to sort the rows in such a way that a row with {r_id, p_id} = x should come below the row with {r_id, a_id} = x.

Comment: Please post the full criteria for the sort.

Comment: I can understand the ordering for r_id = 9.  But I can't figure it out for r_id = 10

Comment: The data in the table and the data in the result are different: There is no p_id 12 in the data but you do have one in the result. Could you show us the correct data and result?

Comment: @Frank: Edited- While copying the tables I missed last character both in input and expected output. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the answer to your previous question, gives the following...

```
WITH RECURSIVE sub(s_id, s_r_id, s_a_id, s_p_id, row) AS (
    SELECT id, r_id, a_id, p_id, 1 AS row FROM foo WHERE p_id = 0
UNION ALL
    SELECT id, r_id, a_id, p_id, (row + 1)  FROM foo JOIN sub ON s_a_id = p_id AND s_r_id = r_id
)
SELECT * FROM sub ORDER BY s_r_id, row;
```

Comment: Edited- While copying the tables I missed last character both in input and expected output

Comment: This slight modification to your previous question's answer should work then.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Well, Is `AND s_r_id = r_id` this needed

Comment: It will still work with the `AND s_r_id = r_id` predicate, which is present due to the description given by the OP.  It also acts as a safety net incase a_id/p_id are not unique across multiple instances of r_id.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the ORDER BY:

```
WITH RECURSIVE sub(s_id, s_r_id, s_a_id, s_p_id, row) AS (
    SELECT id, r_id, a_id, p_id, 1 AS row FROM foo WHERE p_id = 0
UNION ALL
    SELECT id, r_id, a_id, p_id, (row + 1)  FROM foo JOIN sub ON s_a_id = p_id
)
SELECT * FROM sub
ORDER BY s_r_id ASC, row ASC
;
```