# SQL: Order of output

Tags: postgresql, performance, recursive-query

I was checking the docs of postgresql for Recursive queries where I got an example.

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
    VALUES (1)
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 100
)
SELECT sum(n) FROM t
```

Is the above statement same as 100 SELECT statements. From the docs:

`Recursive queries are typically used to deal with hierarchical or tree-structured data.`

If I want to sort the hierarchical structure based on some criteria will it be advisable to recursive query. eg. [SQL Query: Fetch ordered rows from a table - II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041836/sql-query-fetch-ordered-rows-from-a-table-ii) and the accepted answer. Should the data be retrieved from the DB and then sorted in memory. Or RECURSIVE query will be more **effcient** !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on your schema design, hardware/OS, configuration, and volume of data loaded.  Run it both ways with explain and explain analyze and pick the fastest over several typical queries.

Even if I had enough information to guess your schema and exemplar data, any answer good for me may not the good for yo.